# How to edit user id in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

Right now for my rails app (using devise and active admin), I am having user ids  as  serial numerals depending upon the serial of user id creation, i.e. first time I got user id 1, then again signed up with different details and then got user id 2 and then 3 and so on.
But I want to have custom user ids, like greg51 or michel7as or something like that asked during user signup page
How do I do it?

Comment: those fields should be username instead of ids

Comment: what is the purpose of this change? because ids in the database has to be unique and strings like greg51 like id is not a good idea, It´better use uuids. Or if your purpose is change for friendly urls without ids you can use this gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Answer (score 2):

If you want to login with a username or an email, just follow devise instructions in: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address.

If you want to find a user using other fields you can `@user.find_by(username: params[:username])` or whatever field you want in your controllers.

However, you should not change the `id` for a new field (username, email or whatever). Rails generates an `id` in all tables it creates and uses the `id` as a primary key. The primary key should never be changed as it will be used in other tables as references. For this purpose, it uses a sequence field in the database, which creates unique integer values (it increments the last sequence value and returns it as the new `id`) and guarantees that several transactions cannot get the same value (so no other record will have the same `id`).

Besides the primary key, you can define many other unique fields, such as **username**, **email**, **document_id**, etc. Although these fields can also be unique (and can be forced to be unique using a database constraint and the `validates uniqueness` in rails, they are not used as primary key (so you can change them later and no references will be affected).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called vanity URLs where you let the users provide a more human friendly identifier for use in URLs. The column used is often called the *slug* column.

This is not a replacement for primary key ids, either in the form of an auto-incrementing integer column or UUIDs which is basically the same thing but it uses a random generated string instead to solve problems related to scalability. Primary keys are how your database tables refer to one another. Replacing it with a user generated value is possible but not a good idea at all.

To add a "username" feature in Devise you need to:

- Add the username column with a migration. Make sure it has a unique constraint.
- Validate and ensure that the username is URL safe and unique.
- Alter the way Warden looks up users from the database to use the `id` or `username` column.
- Change the way devise looks up users in its controllers to use the `id` or `username` column.

See:

- [Devise WIKI: Allow users to sign in using their username or email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)
- [Stringex - library for slugging strings](https://github.com/rsl/stringex)
- [Friendly-id - the “Swiss Army bulldozer” of slugging and permalink plugins for ActiveRecord.](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Answer (score -1):

Add a field to your user model:

```
rails g migraton AddUsernamaToUser username:string
```

Then add a field to your devise form:

```
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4201
```

And you'll be able to ask for a username.